# Tokenizing a string of expression

Tags: c++

I have a string in the following form:

```
(1 + 2 - 3) / 5
```

Where I want to extract numbers / operators and put them into separate container. What's the best way to do it? Thanks!

update:

The string doesn't necessarily have "ws" between them. For example,

```
(1+2 - 3)/5
```

should be correctly processed.

Comment: strchr("+-")...   Check out ANTLR if you require advanced forms of parsing.

Comment: Boost Spirit does this. Here is an article that [parses exactly what you describe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8516/An-Introduction-to-the-Boost-Spirit-Parser-framewo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually wanting to evaluate that expression then tokenization will not be enough. What you may want instead is the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm). This produces a nice stack of operators and values which you can then evaluate to get an answer to an expression.

This algorithm was the basis of my parser for [Leaf](http://leaflang.org/). I extract individual tokens using a `boost::regex` and skip over the space. Handling the unary '-' is perhaps the trickiest part.

If you truly just want to extract the digits and operators into containers then just use two regexes. One matches all numbers, one matches all operators. Look at the boost regex token iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any tips for implementing the unary minus?

Comment: It is a right associative operator with a high precedence. There is a conditional in the algortihm that mentions left precedence, the unary minus is thus right. High precedence since it applies before most other operators.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't always have separators, you could use `flex` or `flex++` to build a scanner for you.  You'd give it regular expressions, and it would take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks! I'd try out flex too

Answer (score 1):

If there are guaranteed to be spaces between the numbers and operators, then using e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and the normal input operator `>>` will work fine, as the input operator separates on space.

Otherwise you have to read one character at a time, and check what class it is. Like if it's a digit then you have a number, if it's a space then ignore it, or if it's something else then it's probably an operator.

As it seems there may be no spaces between operators (like in your example) then you have to go for the second way. You might want to do a search for "lexer" or "lexical analysis".

---

Some simple pseudo-code to get you started:

```
struct token
{
    enum
    {
        NUMBER,
        OPERATOR
    } type;

    int         num; // If `type` is `NUMBER`
    std::string op;  // If `type` is `OPERATOR`
};

token get_token()
{
    char c = get_single_char();

    // Skip whitespace
    while (std::isspace(c))
        c = get_single_char();

    if (std::isdigit(c))
    {
        // A number
        int n = 0;

        while (std::isdigit(c))
        {
            n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
            c = get_single_char();
        }

        // Here we have gotten one character to many, put it back
        put_back_char(c);

        token t = { NUMBER, n, "" };
        return t;
    }

    // We have an operator
    token t;
    t.type = token::OPERATOR;
    t.op += c;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, I would use strtok()

Example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/